# Access VBA, Link to Oracle and run SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, vba

I am wondering if it is possible using vba in access is to create a database and link it with a oracle sql developer database and run a certain SQL code.

I would like to do this for many years about 20+ years. there are millions of rows for each so it would be best to create an access database for each year.

Is there a way to do this, if not what is the best way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: If you have sql developer, why not simply run your code with that?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use an Access database and link it to an Oracle database. Anything with millions of rows should not be in Access, IMHO.

Comment: I am using Access with SQL Server big linked tables and it works like a charm! So why not?

Answer (score 1):

If you can create an ODBC data source pointing to your Oracle database, then you can add the tables from this database into Access as linked tables. You can then do all the normal Access things with these tables, and you can create pass-through queries if you want to run SQL commands. [Click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access) for Microsoft's description of how to set up pass-through queries.

By the way, if all the data on the Oracle side is in one set of database tables, then there's no advantage to setting up multiple Access databases for separate years.